# Error en transacciones , mezcla en las peticiones a la Base de datos en hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

ya no sé por donde buscar para corregir este error, primero comentando que esto no ocurre en un ambiente de pruebas local, este error solo sale en modo producción en el servidor, dicho error me parece ilogico y no debería pasar , es el siguiente :

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Table 'ArticuloCarrito' doesn't exist
```

Estoy utilizando Java + hibernate , tengo una arquitectura como esta :

Entidades -> Persistencia -> Negocios -> (Beans)WEB

Esa entidad "ArticuloCarrito" solo es una entidad para recibir información de un Procedimiento Almacenado, no es una tabla de la base datos como tal, y es la siguiente :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.sbcm.shoppingcart.entity.custom;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations.Immutable;

/**
 *
 * @author death
 */
@Entity
@Immutable
public class ArticuloCarrito implements Serializable {

   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_arts", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long idArts;

    @Column
    private String numart;

    @Column
    private String descripcion;

    @Column
    private String unidad;

    @Column
    private String marca;

    @Column
    private String modelo;

    @Column
    private String linea;

    @Column
    private String familia;

    @Column
    private String categoria;

    @Column
    private String numdep;

    @Column
    private Float impuesto1;

    @Column
    private Float impuesto2;

    @Column
    private String divisa;

    @Column
    private Float precio1;

    @Column
    private Float precio2;

    @Column
    private Float precio3;

    @Column
    private Float precio4;

    @Column
    private Float precio5;

    @Column
    private String obs;

    @Column
    private Integer eskit;

    @Column
    private String otrosdatos;

    @Column
    private Float pjedesc;

    @Column
    private Integer oferta;

    @Column
    private int statusweb;

    @Column
    private Float precioFinal;

    @Column
    private Float descuentoPromo;

    @Column
    private int existenciart;

    @Column
    private Float preciowDesc;

    @Column
    private Double subTotal;

    @Column
    private Integer cantidad;
    
    @Column
    private Integer idPromo;

    public ArticuloCarrito() {

    }

    public ArticuloCarrito(Long idArts, String numart, String descripcion, String unidad, String marca, String modelo, String linea, String familia, String categoria, String numdep, Float impuesto1, Float impuesto2, String divisa, Float precio1, Float precio2, Float precio3, Float precio4, Float precio5, String obs, Integer eskit, String otrosdatos, Float pjedesc, Integer oferta, int statusweb, Float precioFinal, Float descuentoPromo, int existenciart, Float preciowDesc, Double subTotal, Integer cantidad,Integer idPromo) {
        this.idArts = idArts;
        this.numart = numart;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.unidad = unidad;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.linea = linea;
        this.familia = familia;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.numdep = numdep;
        this.impuesto1 = impuesto1;
        this.impuesto2 = impuesto2;
        this.divisa = divisa;
        this.precio1 = precio1;
        this.precio2 = precio2;
        this.precio3 = precio3;
        this.precio4 = precio4;
        this.precio5 = precio5;
        this.obs = obs;
        this.eskit = eskit;
        this.otrosdatos = otrosdatos;
        this.pjedesc = pjedesc;
        this.oferta = oferta;
        this.statusweb = statusweb;
        this.precioFinal = precioFinal;
        this.descuentoPromo = descuentoPromo;
        this.existenciart = existenciart;
        this.preciowDesc = preciowDesc;
        this.subTotal = preciowDesc* subTotal;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.idPromo=idPromo;
    }

     public Long getIdArts() {
        return idArts;
    }

    public void setIdArts(Long idArts) {
        this.idArts = idArts;
    }

    public String getNumart() {
        return numart;
    }

    public void setNumart(String numart) {
        this.numart = numart;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getUnidad() {
        return unidad;
    }

    public void setUnidad(String unidad) {
        this.unidad = unidad;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getLinea() {
        return linea;
    }

    public void setLinea(String linea) {
        this.linea = linea;
    }

    public String getFamilia() {
        return familia;
    }

    public void setFamilia(String familia) {
        this.familia = familia;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getNumdep() {
        return numdep;
    }

    public void setNumdep(String numdep) {
        this.numdep = numdep;
    }

    public Float getImpuesto1() {
        return impuesto1;
    }

    public void setImpuesto1(Float impuesto1) {
        this.impuesto1 = impuesto1;
    }

    public Float getImpuesto2() {
        return impuesto2;
    }

    public void setImpuesto2(Float impuesto2) {
        this.impuesto2 = impuesto2;
    }

    public String getDivisa() {
        return divisa;
    }

    public void setDivisa(String divisa) {
        this.divisa = divisa;
    }

    public Float getPrecio1() {
        return precio1;
    }

    public void setPrecio1(Float precio1) {
        this.precio1 = precio1;
    }

    public Float getPrecio2() {
        return precio2;
    }

    public void setPrecio2(Float precio2) {
        this.precio2 = precio2;
    }

    public Float getPrecio3() {
        return precio3;
    }

    public void setPrecio3(Float precio3) {
        this.precio3 = precio3;
    }

    public Float getPrecio4() {
        return precio4;
    }

    public void setPrecio4(Float precio4) {
        this.precio4 = precio4;
    }

    public Float getPrecio5() {
        return precio5;
    }

    public void setPrecio5(Float precio5) {
        this.precio5 = precio5;
    }

    public String getObs() {
        return obs;
    }

    public void setObs(String obs) {
        this.obs = obs;
    }

    public Integer getEskit() {
        return eskit;
    }

    public void setEskit(Integer eskit) {
        this.eskit = eskit;
    }

    public String getOtrosdatos() {
        return otrosdatos;
    }

    public void setOtrosdatos(String otrosdatos) {
        this.otrosdatos = otrosdatos;
    }

    public Float getPjedesc() {
        return pjedesc;
    }

    public void setPjedesc(Float pjedesc) {
        this.pjedesc = pjedesc;
    }

    public Integer getOferta() {
        return oferta;
    }

    public void setOferta(Integer oferta) {
        this.oferta = oferta;
    }

    public int getStatusweb() {
        return statusweb;
    }

    public void setStatusweb(int statusweb) {
        this.statusweb = statusweb;
    }

    public Float getPrecioFinal() {
        return precioFinal;
    }

    public void setPrecioFinal(Float precioFinal) {
        this.precioFinal = precioFinal;
    }

    public Float getDescuentoPromo() {
        return descuentoPromo;
    }

    public void setDescuentoPromo(Float descuentoPromo) {
        this.descuentoPromo = descuentoPromo;
    }

    public int getExistenciart() {
        return existenciart;
    }

    public void setExistenciart(int existenciart) {
        this.existenciart = existenciart;
    }

    public Float getPreciowDesc() {
        return preciowDesc;
    }

    public void setPreciowDesc(Float preciowDesc) {
        this.preciowDesc = preciowDesc;
    }


    public Integer getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(Integer cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }


    public Double getSubTotal() {
        if (cantidad < 1) {
            cantidad = 1;
        }
        subTotal = preciowDesc.doubleValue() * cantidad;
        return subTotal;
    }

    public void setSubTotal(Double subTotal) {
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }
    

    public Integer getId_promo() {
        return idPromo;
    }

    public void setIdPromo(Integer idPromo) {
        this.idPromo = idPromo;
    }

}
```

Creo que ya revolvi mucho la pregunta, en resumen me marca ese error de que la tabla no existe en la BD cuando ni si quiera debe existir, pero el error solo sale en el servidor :/

EDITADO:

Olvide darle seguimiento a la pregunta, al final se soluciono, el problema era utilizar un DAO generico para muchas transacciones, en algun punto del mundo de las transacciones de la base de datos alguna transacción era mas rapida que otra o se sobreponian, se soluciono haciendole un DAO a cada entidad

Comment: ese es el problema: no es una tabla de la base datos. Entonces porque la anotaste como @Entity. Creo que en tu misma pregunta te respondes tu mismo.

Comment: @abrahamhs sin ese tag las transacciones de hibernate hacia esa entidad no funcionan marca lo siguiente :

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.sbcm.shoppingcart.entity.custom.ArticuloCarrito

Comment: Eso es a lo que me refiero, tu lógica necesita la tabla

Comment: La respuesta debe ir en el campo respuesta, no como edicion a la pregunta.. igual, la respuesta tampoco es clara..